# Can I calculate CRC-32 for 9-bytes of data when I have access to an 8-byte parallel CRC logic?

Tags: crc, crc32

I have VHDL code for parallel CRC-32 calculator that takes 8-bytes of input data at once. I am gonna call it "CRC_32_8" module.

I am trying to use this module, CRC_32_8, to calculate CRC-32 over 9-bytes of input data. But getting wrong results.

What I did is:
First, I calculated CRC-32 over eight-least-significant-bytes of input data using CRC_32_8 module.
Then, I feed the CRC-32 result alongwith the remaining 1-byte of input data to CRC_32_8. But I am getting the wrong results.

I checked my results using an online CRC calculator: 
https://www.lammertbies.nl/comm/info/crc-calculation.html

The CRC polynomial I am using is :
0x04C11DB7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can come up with seven-bytes that can be prepended to a message that leaves the CRC-32 unchanged. You can then precede your nine bytes with that sequence to feed 16 bytes to your eight-at-a-time calculator. Here is one such sequence in hexadecimal, assuming that your CRC is reflected, as is the standard CRC-32 using that polynomial:

`56 a5 79 b9 00 00 00`

Comment: Hi @Mark, maybe I am doing it wrong but it's not working for me. For example my input number is 0x112233445566778899, correct CRC-32 : 0x2E2A7F10. But when I generate the CRC for 0x112233445566778899_56_a5_79_b9_00_00_00 I get CRC-32 : 0x5636CC72

Comment: oh. I made a mistake. You mean I calculate the CRC on 0x56_a5_79_b9_00_00_00_112233445566778899. This way it's correct. Maybe I should have asked this in a bit different way. Actually, I don't know the input length at the start of this calculation. All I know is the input comes every cycle which is 8-bytes wide (not necessarily all bytes valid). I need to calculate CRC-32 eight-byte-at-a-time and if I do not have 8-byte valid input in any cycle then I have to use the trick. Which brings me to another question: How did you come up with 56 a5 79 b9 00 00 00

Comment: Should I ask another question for this?

Comment: I used a [program I wrote called "spoof"](https://github.com/madler/spoof).

Comment: Ok. Is there a way I can calculate the CRC-32 if I do not know the input size. I mean, I am getting an 8-byte input every time but there can be an input for which not all the 8-bytes are valid. e.g. I got 0x1122334455667788 at a time, then 0x99aabbccddeeff11 and then 0x2233. So, in that case, I can't use the above method. Right? Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: I am gonna open another question thread for it. Thanks for your help @Mark.